# Events attached to Jquery object not triggered on re-insert into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I create a jQuery object:

```
var $el = $("<div>");
```

and attach a few events:

```
$el.on(event, selector, callback);
```

I then add the inner html that will eventually trigger those events.
And then I add $el to the document:

```
$(document).html($el);
```

All the events fire as expected. But when I change the contents of the document:

```
$(document).html($another_el);
```

and change it back

```
$(document).html($el);
```

Those same events do not get triggered any more. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the attached JQuery data (such as event handlers), you should explicitly detach() the element before assigning a new element via html().

From the jQuery docs:

- [on .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.

- [on .detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that
>   was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
>   Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.